# Convert C string to C++ string

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, esp32

My program is running on ESP32. I'm retrieving some data from Bluetooth, and the Bluetooth string is a C string. I need to save that data in an RTC_DATA_ATTR String, which is a C++ string.

Just doing `c++string = cstring.c_str();` won't work, since it will just save a pointer to the location in the memory of the C string, and the purpose is to save the data in the RTC memory, so the ESP32 can go to deep sleep without losing the data.

All other data than RTC gets wiped on deep sleep, so there would just be a pointer, pointing to nothing.

How do I get the data copied from the C string to the C++ string?

Any help would be appreciated. A bit of extra info: this is how it is set up at the moment:

```
RTC_DATA_ATTR String ssid;

BLECharacteristic *cSsid = NULL;

ssid = cSsid->getValue().c_str();
```

Comment: you mixed it up. you want a C string from String? `.c_str()` of `String` returns a constant pointer to the internal C string (zero terminated char array) of String which is in heap. but to save it to RTC memory something must copy it to the RTC memory. it is not neccessary to copy it into 'C string' in memory.

Comment: yes, my question is: how do i copy the c string to my rtc memory

Comment: I agree with  @Juraj . I believe you misused the terms cstring and c++ strings. As I understand your question, you have a class  RTC_DATA_ATTR that allocates its content memory (string typed) from the RTC EEPROM. Now you ask how you are able to initialize that Class with content from a "cstring". (as you use `.c_str()` I believe this is also a c++ string) Because I don't know the library RTC_DATA_ATTR is from I can not say how to copy text into a string of that type. You should at least add the library name to the question or give us some information what that type is like.

Comment: Your code would lead to a null pointer exception, which will be silently skipped..

Comment: i have no idea what library the RTC is apart of, I haven't #include any library which it is in

Comment: it doesnt give any error, when i compile it, but in the serial monitor, it println(rtcstring)  just prints clear line, as if rtc string was = null

Comment: i would guess the RTC and Deep_sleep commands come from the installed board in ArduinoIDE

Comment: but all im looking for is a way to copy the value of the string from bluetooth into the RTC string, which in my head the solution should just be todo: =

Comment: `RTC_DATA_ATTR char ssid[33];` `strcpy(ssid, cSsid->getValue().c_str());`

Comment: A null pointer is a runtime error, which you can not see at compile time. In the arduino context you will not recognize the null pointer exception. But I'm sure you get one as you initialized the `BLECharacteristic *cSsid = NULL;` and then used the null pointer `cSsid->getValue()`. Or did I missed something and NULL is an option object? Can C++ handle option objects in the meantime? But anyway whithout knowing the library I can not help you. If you just want to make your string persistent you could probably write it to the FLASH memory. https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-flash-memory/

Comment: solution found, using the strcpy, thanks

Comment: Sorry, now I understand what you tried. Yes it's part of the ESP32 software. And you might not want to store the date in EEPROM, just make it persistent while deep sleep. (I think I should go to sleep now ;-) ) https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-timer-wake-up-deep-sleep/ @Juraj gave you the solution. But the null pointer problem is still there. Or is this not all of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply, using strcpy, and using a char with a given length, works

RTC_DATA_ATTR char ssid["dedicated length"];

strcpy(ssid, cSsid->getValue().c_str(), "dedicated length");